# Maintain HTTP session in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, httprequest, session-cookies, jenkins-pipeline, alm

I want to use [ALM REST API](http://alm-help.saas.hp.com/en/12.50/api_refs/REST/webframe.htm#Overview.htm) inside a Jenkins pipeline. To use this API I need to follow those steps :

1. authentication + sign-in (session cookie created)
2. get what I need
3. sign-out

I also need to **maintain** a session :

> Although RESTful applications are ideally stateless, the ALM platform requires sessions to manage locking, client lifetime, and perform other basic tasks.

Using the [HTTP Request Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin), I'm not able to maintain the session.

I have a working solution using curl and the pipeline step "sh" but I would like to do something cleaner, using a step from a plugin/jenkins or some groovy/java solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the ALM REST API, but it sounds like you want to use a normal HTTP-session using cookies, but through Jenkins' `httpRequest`. This does not appear to be easily supported out of the box, but you can do it manually like this:

```java
httpRequest(url: "https://the-url.com/login.php")
def cookieContent = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
httpRequest(
    url: "https://the-url.com/the-thing.php",
    customHeaders: [[name:"Cookie", value:cookieContent]])
```

You'll probably have to play around with the connection to see what the server accepts and returns. Hopefully you can supply the login using the built in `authentication`, but you might need to provide the login in the body like this for example:

```
contentType: "APPLICATION_FORM",
requestBody: "user=${env.USER}&pass=${env.PASS}",
```

Hope this helps.